# How To Create Webstart From Existing Eclipse Installation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, java-web-start

I want to create a java webstart product that includes all of the contents of my current eclipse installation - standard eclipse java edition with some extra plugins that I have developed/downloaded.

There are a number of tutorials showing how to do this for an eclipse RCP application, but I don't want to create an RCP specifically for this purpose (I also tried to do it and never really managed to configure the app to look just like my workbench).

So, is this even possible? Any pointers?

Update: I followed [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-jws/index.html) article, but after deploying my application in the web server and running the jnlp, the jars were downloaded but nothing happened. I tried changing the `eclipse.product` property to other "possible" values, but didn't help.

Comment: You might look through [*Deploying an Eclipse-based application with Java Web Start*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-jws/index.html) and update your question if you encounter a specific problem.

Comment: @trashgod I alreay did. Tried to do it a number of times but nothing worked. I don't get the results from the site. And also, it does not do what I want to do, which is simply take a full eclipse installation and run it using webstart.

Comment: You may want to cite the article in your question; also, indicate where it diverged from the expected result and how it differs from your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the web start software?

Since eclipse doesn't requires installation, and the plugins are installed in the same directory of eclipse why don't you zip your eclipse once you have it configured, and redistribute it as a zip. Even eclipse itself is distributed as zip.